# Insert a document in a document

Tags: java, mongodb, document, nosql

Im using mongodb + java. I tried to insert a new document into an existing document. Lets say I have a collection "Users":

```
{"_id" :{"$oid" : "4dc9..."}, "name" :"Klaus", "gender" :"unknown", "adress" :"null"}
```

Now I would like to update this document where the name == Klaus and add a new document to the key `adress` (wheres now only "null"). So I would like to have something like this:

```
{"_id" :{"$oid" : "4dc9..."}, "name" :"Klaus", "gender" :"unknown", "adress" :{"country" :"Austria", "city": "..."}}
```

How to do it in Java? I tried

```
//DBCollection col "Users"
String json = "{'country': '" + user.country + "', 'city': '" + user.city + "'}";
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);
col.update(new BasicDBObject().append("name", "Klaus"), dbObject); //not working
```

I dont get any errormessage, the new document is just not there. Is something wrong with my json? Or do I need another "update" function, maybe a replace (replace `adress:null` with `adress:new document`)? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your update. At no point do you even specify there should be a field "address". Also note that you're not "inserting" a document within a document here. Rather your setting a field of your top level document to a value that is an embedded document. Use this instead :

```
col.update(new BasicDBObject("name", "Klaus"), new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("address", dbObject)));
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the fast answer its working. At first I tought I dont have to use the key "adress" in the update because its already there in the document - but now its clear. I just have some problems with "$set", I saw on some tutorials that there is always a way to update without "$set" but maybe Im wrong.

Comment: Those tutorials lied ;) The only way that claim holds true is if you overwrite the entire document each time you update it which is less efficient and usually broken. Use $set whenever you can.